# Lxml Xpath does not work with python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, lxml

So I have a code that makes use of lxml.

```
from lxml import html
import os

data = open(filename).read() //works
tree = html.fromstring(data)
word = "haha"
try :
    xpathstring = '//span[contains(@aria-label,"' + word + '")]/text()'
    liste = tree.xpath(xpathstring)
    nombre = liste[0]
except:
    nombre = -1
print(nombre)
```

In Python 2.7 : 772

In Python 3.5 :

```
File "test.py", line 6, in extract
nombre = liste[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I cannot figure why Lxml does not work in Python 3. I made tests from the Python 3 interactive mode and no xpath seems to work.

Edit:

```
>>> html.tostring(tree)
```

In Python 2: It returns the whole html string
In Python 3: [screen][1]

**Last edit:**
Fixed it !

The filename needs to be opened in binary format :

```
data = open(filename,"rb").read()
```

Comment: Remove the bare `try..except` and rerun the code with Python3. That way we can see what exception occurs. Please post the full traceback error message.

Comment: @unutbu I edited. Basically nothing is returned from the xpath method.

Comment: Does `html.tostring(tree)` return a sensible result? Can you find the desired `772` inside that string?

Comment: @unutbu it does not..

Comment: Can you prepare a shortened version of the contents of `filename` and post `repr(open(shortfile).read())` here so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @unutbu : I realized where the problem came from, see last edit. Thank you for your help !